# Include page depending url (php)

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a php code that include php file depending the page url. (I know wordpess  do something similar)

I got this stupid code, but I'm sure I'm missing something..

```
$url = explode('/', trim(($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), '/'));

if ($url[0]==urlencode ('news))
     require_once 'cpt/category/news-page.php';
if ($url[0]==urlencode ('home))
     require_once 'cpt/category/home-page.php';
```

Comment: please first see how to use explode function in php

Comment: I don't think this is a regex question.

Comment: Fix the syntax and you're good

Comment: I don't think this is how Wordpress does this. WP sends everything to index.php, which parses the URL and shows the proper page

Answer (score 0):

$current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

```
if (strpos($current_url,"my-current-url")) {
    require_once 'cpt/category/news-page.php';
}else if(strpos($current_url,"my-current-url")){
    require_once 'cpt/category/news-page.php';
}
```

Here is a short example it might help you.

I've se the url of the page as $current_url. and we do a simple IF string poses something like "your url" and if it does then it does what you need.

Hoped that it helps, pretty sure you can set it up to work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use an Front Controller Pattern. All requests go through index.php, and then you can use a routing component to parse the url for you. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing.html for a good router. It ships with Symfony, but will work independently.

Answer (score -2):

You could use some things like this: yoururl.php?act=news&para=latest

```
if($_GET['act']=='news')
{
   require_once("cpt/category/news-page.php");
}
```